# JQuery is not defined although it's loaded

Tags: jquery

jQuery is not defined although it's loaded and `$` is working. I've got this error while using `JQuery.parseJSON`.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `JQuery is not defined

index.php:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>comment box</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="comment_insert.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
</head>
```

When I used `jquery.parsejson` I got an error that JQuery is not defined

comment_insert.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $( '#comment-post-btn').click(function(){
        comment_post_btn_click();
    });
});

function comment_post_btn_click() {
    var _comment= $('#comment-post-text').val();
    var _userId= $('#userId').val();
    var _userName= $('#userName').val();

    if (_comment.length > 0 && _userId != null) {
        $.post("comment_insert.php", {
            task: "comment_insert",
            userId: _userId,
            comment: _comment
        }).success(function(data) {
            //task: insert html into the ul/li
            comment_insert(JQuery.parsejson(data));
            console.log("ResponseText: " + data);
        });
```

Comment: Note that JavaScript is case-sensitive. Your code should use `jQuery`, not `JQuery` and it's `parseJSON()`, not `parsejson()`. Also, you don't need to parse the JSON response as jQuery does this for you - the `data` variable in the `success` handler will already be an object.

Comment: Also it is strange, that you switch between using `$` and `jQuery` in your code.

Comment: it's just a tutorial and i'm following what instructor was doing .. it's my first time to write jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are case sensitive, so you must use `jQuery`, or `$`. Also, `parseJSON()` is the function, not `parsejson()`

Change this line:

```
comment_insert(JQuery.parsejson(data));
```

To this line:

```
comment_insert($.parseJSON(data));
```

or:

```
comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
```

Comment: Note that while this will stop the error, the call to `parseJSON` is redundant as jQuery will automatically do it for you. In fact, calling `parseJSON` on the object in the `data` variable will actually *cause* another error.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Is there a source that says whatever is passed back from the $.post function is JSON?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ `dataType`
Type: String
*The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).* When JSON is detected (or specified) the response will be automatically deserialised.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ DataType: *"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)*

Comment: So if a call is to a php function, like here, and then the return is just a string, it will return a string in a JSON format?

Comment: If it's just a string, it will be left as a string. If it's a string in JSON format, it'll be deserialised to an object. Given that the OP is trying to use `parseJSON` I am assuming that they are attempting to retrieve JSON, even though it's not explicitly specified.

Comment: So in this case, it would be best to check if it is a JSON object before parsing as JSON?

Comment: Not really, as jQuery will *already* have converted it for you when it detects the format of the response.